# nodejs error (nodeproxy.node) setting up Mozilla Open Badges

Tags: node.js, npm, openbadge

I've been going through a tutorial for setting up a self hosted version of Mozilla Open Badges using this guide https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-badgekit/wiki/BadgeKit-Self-Hosting-Guide

I've come across many problems with it, under a Windows 7 environment. Some of these I've been able to fix as I've gone along, e.g. setting environment variables and installing other software as required. There is **a lot** of stuff that the guide doesn't specifically mention, but that's just a learning curve I guess.

However when I've got towards the end of the tutorial and am trying to run 'openbadges-badgekit' it fails. I get this error and haven't been able to find a fix:

```
    C:\xampp\htdocs\openbadges-badgekit\app>node index.js
    module.js:339
        throw err;
        ^
    Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/nodeproxy.node'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\openbadges-badgekit\node_modules\clie
    nt-sessions\node_modules\node-proxy\lib\node-proxy.js:1:90)
        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I've done `npm install` and all the other steps of the tutorial.

Environment:

Windows 7 (Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601])

npm 2.14.7

node v4.2.3

Comment: I was having trouble with this myself. I ended up contacting someone from Open Badges and they said that the self-hosting guide is going to be updated in January with new options and instructions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue April '16, do you know if the guide was updated?

Comment: @Andy2K11 it says at the top that the page was last edited on Nov 27, 2014 so I'd guess not! I've had a quick look through it and it seems exactly the same as when I last checked it out in December 2015 unfortunately.